# .NET Core: getting which url controller actions uses

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

In `AccountController` I have four routes for a single action:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpGet("/go", Order = 2)]
[HttpGet("/ex", Order = 2)]
[HttpGet("/men", Order = 2)]
[HttpGet("/ing", Order = 2)]
public async Task<IActionResult> Register()
{
    return View();
}
```

I can reach this action with for example `localhost:222/men`

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Register( RegisterViewModel model)
{
    model.Code = Request.Path.Value;// HERE i want to get url path (/men,/ing ...)
    var platformResponse = await _factory.RegisterAsync(model);

    return View();
}
```

How can I get this route value?

`Request.Path.Value` returns -> "Account/Register"

Comment: It looks like the *real* question is how to retrieve `ing` as a parameter. You could try `[HttpGet("{it}")]` and add `string it` as an action parameter

Comment: HttpContext.Request.Path.Value would return the path value of your current path,would not be affected by former request,If you reached Register Page with Get method and want to get the path value in next  post request ,you need to store it in Cookie/Session

Comment: The route you registed with HttpGet attribute would not affect the Action with Httppost attribute under the same name, and you reached the post Action with the path /Account/Register not /men

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current value of the route by using Request.query.

```
 string valueOfRoute = HttpContext.Request.Query["routevalue"]
```

Notice that route here is the value of routevalue. like if you have in your url: `localhost:8080/?routevalue=ing` so you should get the value of the route value.

Source:https://makolyte.com/aspnetcore-getting-query-string-values/